# Create FileManager (FileBrowser, ImageBrowser) with Telerik Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: telerik-mvc

I was waiting Telerik along time to create this control, now I created it on my own with Telerik Kendo UI and sharing for everyone. I think many peoples need this so much.
Please see bellow
Happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Created project at: https://github.com/vndevil/TelerikFileManager
And this is demo in image

[image: FileManager with Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC by VnDevil]

[image: FileManager with Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC by VnDevil]